# How to update whole column in sql server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-update

I want to update a column values in sql server table after copying those value from some other table. i.e.

where I have tested this query but not succeeded

```
update subset_aminer.dbo.sub_aminer_paper 
set sub_aminer_paper.p_abstract = 
    (select aminer_paper.p_abstract 
     from aminer.dbo.aminer_paper 
     where pid IN (86257, 116497, 119248, 135555, 147554,
                   149720, 173254, 191333, 196650, 196656,
                   .....long list of other values ......
                   1727408, 1737809, 2034956)
    )
```

I have to copy data from other database table to my destination database table. So that's y using `subset_aminer.dbo.subset_aminer_paper.p_abstract` and `aminer.dbo.aminer_paper.p_abstract`

Please help with acknowledgements. Thanks

Comment: can you tell me with sample data how you want to update ??

Comment: @Jonathan I just want to get p_abstract text values from aminer table to insert into subset_aminer table......the column names are same

Comment: both the tables have common id even though both are in different databases

Comment: @Jonathan yeah coz subset_aminer is a subset copy of aminer database

Comment: @Jonathan what will be the solution ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update subset_aminer.dbo.sub_aminer_paper SI
set SI.p_abstract = AP.p_abstract 
     from aminer.dbo.aminer_paper AP
     where AP.pid IN (86257, 116497, 119248, 135555, 147554,
                   149720, 173254, 191333, 196650, 196656,
                   .....long list of other values ......
                   1727408, 1737809, 2034956) AND AP.ID = SI.ID
```

Comment: it is giving error for SI and AP alias we have used

Comment: it's just table alias names for sub_aminer_paper and aminer_paper then why it will give error ..can you please put your exact code then we can have clear look @maliks

Comment: I have used same query as told by you

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion,

```
UPDATE subset_aminer.dbo.sub_aminer_paper
SET p_abstract=aminer.dbo.aminer_paper.p_abstract 
FROM aminer.dbo.aminer_paper
WHERE subset_aminer.dbo.sub_aminer_paper.pid IN (86257, 116497, 119248, 135555, 147554,
               149720, 173254, 191333, 196650, 196656,
               .....long list of other values ......
               1727408, 1737809, 2034956)
```

Comment: what result will it be using MERGE, i just need single table values not both

Comment: yeah, first it will check whether the id is present in both table , if its present then it will update . Merge is to check whether the id is present or not, Update will update the id's which u want to update.

Comment: Here merge means not merging 2 tables , its just used to Match the ID , as u need :) just try it.

Comment: but I have to update for some specific pID not for every pID

Comment: CHECK THIS, I HAVE EDITED.